# Update UITableViewCell tag property after row is moved

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tags

In my application I need to be able to keep track identify which cell a UITextField comes from when I commit the editing changes in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. To do this, I just set the tag property on the cell's text field in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

When the cells are moved, this causes a bit of trouble. For example, if I move the bottom cell up to the top, delete the cell that is now at the bottom, and then try to edit the cell I just placed at the top, my app will crash because the tag property is still at 8 (or another number), but there aren't this many elements in my datasource.

I tried to fix this problem by updating the tag in `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSString *siteToMove = [[sites objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]] retain];

    [sites removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
    [sites insertObject:siteToMove atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];

    if ([toIndexPath section] == 1) {
        [[(BookmarkTextEntryTableViewCell *)[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath] textField] setTag:[toIndexPath row]];
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because `(BookmarkTextEntryTableViewCell *)[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath]` returns the cell that was there *before* moving the row.

Answer (score 1):

In your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath` method, you can iterate through all the `UITextField`s that you might've added as subViews to the table and then check and set the new tag as-

```
for (UIView* subview in [[self tableView] subviews]) {
 if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {  
  if(subview.tag==oldTag){
    subview.tag = newTag;
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

EDIT: On second thought, you can just reload the table data in case that resets all the remaining cell's tags too.